# How to set -Djava.class.path from absolute to relative path?

Tags: java

I want to modify this line:

```
javaw -Djava.class.path="$OMROOT\JavaAPI\rhapsody.jar;T:\OpenUnitInNotepad\Output\OpenWithNotepad.jar"
```

The rhapsody.jar part should stay the same. However I want the change the OpenWithNotepad.jar part to a relative path, if it's possible. As far as I know the first part changes the current directory so that might be a problem.

Comment: I don’t think the current directory is changed.

Comment: >As far as I know the first part changes the current directory so that might be a problem.< No it doesn't

Comment: Then can I just write .\Output\OpenWithNotepad.jar if my current directory is "." if I want a relative path?

Comment: That should work.

Comment: Well, for some reason it didn't.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. It worked, just it had to be made relative to the rpy file not he hep file.